# How to order data in Firebase using the URL?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase URL

https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/cms/file.json?print=pretty&orderBy="$priority"

I have added the parameter orderBy and tried following all combinations of the docs but it is not firing. I want my data ordered by last entry I have also got timeStamps `transCreation` inside my data:

```
{
  "00hym5km2tf08s38fr-ivjgnsw6" : {
    "notes" : "",
    "transCreation" : "11/15/2016, 4:14:07 PM",
    "transId" : "00hym5km2tf08s38fr-ivjgnsw6",
    "transModified" : "11/15/2016, 4:14:07 PM",
    "transNameArabic" : "استخدم كعنوان الدفع الافتراضي",
    "transNameEn" : "Use as my default billing address",
    "transStatus" : "FIXED"
  },
  "00x6lc2f840fubygy14i-ivam9zl8" : {
    "notes" : "",
    "transCreation" : "11/9/2016, 11:41:25 AM",
    "transId" : "00x6lc2f840fubygy14i-ivam9zl8",
    "transModified" : "11/9/2016, 11:41:25 AM",
    "transNameArabic" : "حالة طلب الشراء",
    "transNameEn" : "Order Status",
    "transStatus" : "FIXED"
  },
  "00y5h85rhhz4niza1yvi-ivan9o5w" : {
    "notes" : "",
    "transCreation" : "11/9/2016, 12:09:10 PM",
    "transId" : "00y5h85rhhz4niza1yvi-ivan9o5w",
    "transModified" : "11/9/2016, 12:09:10 PM",
    "transNameArabic" : "يرجى تعيين طريقة الشحن",
    "transNameEn" : "Please specify a shipping method",
    "transStatus" : "FIXED"
  },
  "01aw-ixzxigpa" : {
    "notes" : "",
    "transCreation" : "1/16/2017, 2:09:35 PM",
    "transId" : "01aw-ixzxigpa",
    "transModified" : "1/16/2017, 2:09:35 PM",
    "transNameArabic" : "تم تأكيد طلبيتك بنجاح",
    "transNameEn" : "YOUR ORDER HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY PROCESSED",
    "transStatus" : "FIXED"
  },
  "01b0l16b6td3usxajor-ivaucr54" : {
    "notes" : "",
    "transCreation" : "11/9/2016, 3:27:31 PM",
    "transId" : "01b0l16b6td3usxajor-ivaucr54",
    "transModified" : "11/9/2016, 3:27:31 PM",
    "transNameArabic" : "تشغيل تنبيهات السعر",
    "transNameEn" : "Sign up for price alert",
    "transStatus" : "FIXED"
  }
}
```

Can I do this via the URL?

Comment: The REST API for Firebase returns a JSON object, where the keys are by definition unordered. So while you can filter the data on the server, you will need to re-order it on the client when you use the REST API. I'm pretty sure we covered this before, so I'll find a duplicate.

Comment: Can I not do this via the URL though?

Comment: `  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"transNameEn\", for path \"/cms/translations\", to the rules"` I try orderBy=$key it does not sort the data and if I try orderBy transNameEn or transCreation it fires an error

Comment: That means you didn't define an index, which is required for the REST API. The error message tells you what index to add.

Comment: Can you give me an example URL please. This does not work `/translations.json?print=pretty&orderBy="transNameEn"&.indexOn=transNameEn`

Comment: You can only add indexes in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/), **not** in the query itself. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data